# Appengine - Several upload handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, image-uploading

What's the best way to have different upload handlers for gae in python?

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, test):
        self.response.out.write(test)
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")



class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/')
```

This code works fine but always call the Uploadhandler at the url /upload

```
 upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/another_url')
```

upload_url still refers to /upload, so whats the best way to redirect from form A to upload handler A and from form B to upload handler B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss the "/_ah/" at the beginning of the url? Afaik, create_upload_url always points to something like /_ah/upload/xxxx (thats the url you upload to) and then invokes an internal redirect to the url (/upload or /another_url) you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The uploadhandler receives a callback with the uploaded file. To pass other information, like webapp2 session data, you can use multiple inheritance and use session data to find out which redirect to use.

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, webapp2.RequestHandler):

....
```